# Shortcut for OK button in SSMS filter dialog

Tags: ssms, ssms-2017

What is the shortcut for OK button in SSMS filter dialog? When I filter tables I have this dialog box. After typing MyPhrase in Name field when I hit Enter key the cursor goes down to next field Schema. I want to use keyboard to hit OK instead of go down to another field.

[image]

Comment: I removed the <sql> tag, since the SQL language has nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can activate the OK button by:

1. Type the query.
2. Press <kbd>tab</kbd>
3. Press <kbd>enter</kbd>

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will leave the question open for some time. Maybe someone suggests a direct hit. If not, I will accept your strange sequence. Thank you.